# Check wheter atomic ptr is not initialized in gcc 4.4.7 (without nullptr)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, gcc4

During re-factorization of singleton class to be thread safe ([fallowing Herb Sutter advice how to write proper double-check locking](https://youtu.be/c1gO9aB9nbs?t=1081)) I came across problem with my version of compiler (gcc 4.4.7 with --std=c++0x flag) supporting atomics but not supporting nullptr.

Current code

```
class SingletonClass {
   public:
SingletonClass* getInstance() {
    if (instance == NULL) {
        instance == new SingletonClass();
    }
    return instance;
}

   private:
SingletonClass() = default;
~SingletonClass() = default;

static SingletonClass* instance;};
```

What I would like to achive

```
#include <cstdatomic>
#include <mutex>

class SingletonClass {
   public:
SingletonClass* getInstance() {
    if (instance == NULL) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (m);
        if(instance == NULL){
           instance = new SingletonClass();
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

   private:
 SingletonClass() = default;
~SingletonClass() = default;

static std::atomic<SingletonClass*> instance;
static std::mutex m;
};
```

But this gives me error saying that there is no operator for comparing atomic ptr to NULL

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘SingletonClass* SingletonClass::getInstance()’:
main.cpp:7: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator==’ in ‘SingletonClass::instance == 0l’
main.cpp:7: note: candidates are: operator==(void*, void*) <built-in>
main.cpp:7: note:                 operator==(SingletonClass*, SingletonClass*) <built-in>
```

Since I can't either compare instance ptr to NULL or use nullptr how do I work around it and check whether it is initialized or not ?

Comment: Toolchain dependencies are a thing, but to be sure, can you confirm that you're stuck with 4.4.7?

Comment: Yep, that's something I can't do anything with

Comment: What happens if you cast your `NULL` to be explicitly `void*` or `SingletonClass*` like `if(instance == dynamic_cast<SingletonClass*>(NULL))`

Comment: error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘0l’ (of type ‘long int’) to type ‘class SingletonClass*’ (source is not a pointer)

Comment: error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘0l’ (of type ‘long int’) to type ‘void*’ (source is not a pointer)

Comment: Looks like you've got a weirdly defined (non-C++11-compliant) `NULL` macro... Use `0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use implicit conversion of pointer to bool:

```
SingletonClass* getInstance() {
    if (instance.load()) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (m);
        if(instance.load()){
           instance.store(new SingletonClass());
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

[See it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gnpFk2dMfTS1HU5m)

Note that implicit conversion from `std::atomic<SingletonClass*>` to `SingletonClass*` is possible, but ambiguous in this context. Also, the assignment is ambiguous itself, so `store()` call was added.

---

However, perhaps the solution is simpler - why do you need `std::atomic` at all? You are already locking access to the stored pointer, so you are safe:

```
#include <mutex>

class SingletonClass {
public:
    SingletonClass* getInstance() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (m);
        if (instance == NULL) {
            instance = new SingletonClass();
        }
        return instance;
    }

private:
    SingletonClass() = default;
    ~SingletonClass() = default;

    static SingletonClass* instance;
    static std::mutex m;
};
```

`std::atomic` is used for lockfree access (or at least "hidden lock" access). I can't think of a reason to use both together off the top of my head.

Mutex here is pretty much required - you want to lock whole function as a critical section, or else two threads could create two singleton objects and one would be leaked.

Comment: I agree with @Yksisarvinen on this actually.  Once you have the lock, the `atomic` isn't needed and just complicates things.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think Yksisarvinen's answer above is better.  You already have the lock, don't bother anymore.  Leaving my old answer below.

I'm not sure about the specific GCC version, but if `<atomic>` is there theoretically this should work:

```
SingletonClass* getInstance() {
    if (instance.load() == NULL) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (m);
        if(instance.load() == NULL){
            instance = new SingletonClass();
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

As per [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/load), `load()` should give you what you want, the pointer itself to compare to, which *should* work with NULL.

Good luck on old compilers.  I've had to do that too on occasion due to customer requirements.

Comment: My answer suggests going straight with implicit conversion to bool, but yours [works just as well](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Rt4I58M29rHtK0Xi) . There is an issue with assignment, but it's easily resolved with a `store()` call

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for!